# A question about the product Topology

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\{(x,0)\}\cup X\times (0,1]$ in $X\times[0,1]$ is open?

When $X=\{x,y\}$ and topology is the Sierpinski topology $\tau=\{X,\varnothing ,\{x\}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You can prove directly that $U=\big(X\times[0,1]\big)\setminus\{\langle y,0\rangle\}$ is open in $X\times[0,1]$ by showing that each point of $U$ has an open nbhd contained in $U$. Is $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ open? What about $X\times(0,1]$?

Or you can notice that $U=\big(X\times[0,1]\big)\setminus\{\langle y,0\rangle\}$, so you need only show that $\{\langle y,0\rangle\}$ is closed in $X\times[0,1]$. And $\{\langle y,0\rangle\}=\{y\}\times\{0\}$. Is $\{y\}$ closed in $X$? Is $\{0\}$ closed in $[0,1]$?